# run a .bat file from folder background context menu

Tags: batch-file, contextmenu

I'm trying to run a bat file located at c:\sort2folder.bat from the context menu of the folder background that I am currently in ,IE H:\videos, using the code below.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sort 2 Folder]
@="&Sort 2 Folder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sort 2 Folder\command]
@="C:\\sort2folder.bat \"%V\""
```

The problem is that it seems to be running the sort2folder.bat file in the c: directory instead of changing to the current directory that I'm in.

Comment: You are specifically pushing directory to that holding the batch file, `@pushd %~dp0`, so I would suggest you remove that line! What you should have done was take the code you borrowed, opened a Command Prompt window, and entered each command used followed by **`/?`**, to read and understand how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and suggestion. I have look and read the info on some of the commends, but still can't figure out my error. I had use that @pushd %~dp0 as i was trying to run the bat file from a folder on a NAS drive and was getting

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and suggestion. I have looked and read the info on some of the commends, but still can't figure out my error. I had use that @pushd %~dp0 as i was trying to run the bat file from a network share on a NAS drive and was getting the following message: "UNC path are not supported.   The main problem seems to be the two lines above to add the "sort 2 folder" into the  context menu.  It runs the bat file at the c: location instead of the folder i'm currently in.

Comment: You are passing the target directory as argument 1. So `@pushd "%~1"` in the script may work.